# How does google app time trigger work?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having an issue understanding how Google time triggers work. If a user creates a time trigger, will this function be called for all spreadsheets and users that use the add-on?

When debugging, I created a time trigger programatically which appears in Edit -> Triggers for current project. Will this trigger bind automatically with all spreadsheets?

Comment: A time based trigger is not bound to any Sheet, Form or Doc.  It runs independently of any Google document.  Apps Script can not "call" a trigger.  If an ***event*** happens, the function associated with that trigger will run.  An event can be a time occurring, or a Form being submitted, and other things.  If you want a time based trigger to do something like access many different spreadsheets, then the code would need to open each spreadsheet by it's file ID.  Or, you could do something like get all spreadsheets in a certain folder, and loop through them.

Comment: Suppose there is a form in my addon where the user can select the time and a certain action (function). If two users of my add-on, independently of each other create two identical triggers through this form, it turns out that for two users this function will work simultaneously twice?

Comment: A distinction needs to be made about the two users.  If each of the two users are using your Add-on from a different account, then when each user creates a trigger, each trigger will run independently under each users account.  If two users are trying to create two triggers from the same account, that can never happen.  An Add-on can only create one trigger of each trigger ***type*** per account.

Comment: Okay, as I understand you, this triggers is individual for all accounts. Thank you, it's very helping me.

But what about context? If in function I will use SpreadsheetApp.getActive() - this return me active spreadsheet for time, when user install this trigger?

Comment: Once you install a Google Spreadsheet Add-on, it is *available* to all other spreadsheets.  You do not need to install it again.  ***BUT*** the Add-on is *not* automatically **enabled** for every other spreadsheet.  So the "Active Spreadsheet" is only, each spreadsheet that the Add-on is **enabled** on.  So, you need to provide a way for the user to enable the Add-on for each Sheet that the user wants to use it on.  So, the Add-on *can* find the active spreadsheet that it is enabled on.  Each document can have it's own time trigger.  So every spreadsheet can have it's own time based trigger.

Comment: You can't have one spreadsheet install a time based trigger, and then have that time based trigger access whatever spreadsheet might be open.  The "Active Spreadsheet" is *only* the spreadsheet that the Add-on is *enabled* on.  So, if you wanted to have some code that monitored multiple spreadsheets, from one central place, you couldn't use the "Active Spreadsheet."  One, central script can't know what other spreadsheets are open and active.

Comment: Actually, in order for a user to enable an Add-on, all they need to do, is "use it".  "Using it" probably means that some function gets run, other than "onOpen()"

Answer (score 0):

## A simple way to manage a trigger

I find it helpful to always check to see if there is already a trigger on a given function before I create another.  For example I have a nightly trigger testing some new code in a web app and so I put the function setupNightlyTrigger in the doGet of the webapp so that it only runs whenever I go to that page usually once a day.  It's just a way to make sure the the trigger is setup and running.

```
function setupNightlyTrigger()
{
  if(!isTrigger('resetCount'))
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('resetCount').timeBased().atHour(22).everyDays(1).create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(handlerName)
{
  var r=false;
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++) 
  {
    if (handlerName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()) 
    {
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```